# the devil you know / all the money we have

Tags: clauses, modifiers

In the noun phrases "the devil you know" and "all the money we have" what do we call **you know** and **we have** nowadays beyond "modifier"?

Comment: It looks like a modifier.

Comment: I see that it is a modifier (and tagged the question as such), but wouldn't it have a fancier name, inasmuch as it  not the same as "with horns" or "in the bank" or "holding a pitchfork"?

Comment: Well, that means your question in unclear. Please edit it @Tᴚoɯɐuo :).

Comment: Too generic, like "modifier" :)

Comment: They are reduced relative clauses: the devil [whom] you know, all the money [which] we have.

Comment: Thanks, @StoneyB. I woke up this morning thinking that **you are** in "I don't know which one *you are*" is such a clause.

Answer (score 1):

Those are a Dependent Clauses, with the relative pronouns omitted.

If the relative pronouns were included, the phrases would be "the devil that you know" and "all the money that we have"

The specific type of Dependent Clause in these cases is Adjective Clause.